# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null. Error. How to fix this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have the following view

```
@model CaseConverterModel

<h1 class="text-center fw-bold">Title Case Converter</h1>
<h4 class="text-center">Smart Title Capitalization Tool</h4>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form asp-action="ConvertToTitleCase">
            <textarea id="txtText" class="form-control" style="width:100%"></textarea>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Convert" class="btn btn-primary" />

            <hr />
            <p>@Model.OutPutText</p>
        </form>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Following Controller

```
   public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ConvertToTitleCase(string inputText)
{
    var obj = new CaseConverterModel();
    obj.OutPutText = "this is test";
    return View(nameof(Index), obj);
}
```

Here is the Model

```
public class CaseConverterModel
{
    public string InputText { get; set; }
    public string OutPutText { get; set; }
}
```

When I run it it shows following error message
[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: How do you access the `Index` page in the browser? With `{domain}/{controller}/Index`? If yes, you will get NRE error as your `Index` action didn't pass the model to View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yong Shun said is right.

Your `<p>@Model.OutPutText</p>` need the model value, but in your (get) `Index()` method , you don't pass the model.

Could you try to  use [@Html.DisplayFor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelperdisplayextensions.displayfor?view=aspnetcore-7.0) ?

Below is a work demo, hope it can help you. Make some change in your form like below:

```
        <form asp-action="ConvertToTitleCase">
            <textarea id="txtText" name="inputText" class="form-control" style="width:100%"></textarea>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Convert" class="btn btn-primary" />

            <hr />        
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.OutPutText)</p>
        </form>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Yep.this is working. How comes MODEL.OutPutText not works but @HTML.DisplayFor(m=>m.Output)

Comment: @PrageethLiyanage Because it Returns A new IHtmlContent containing the created HTML. Read [.DisplayFor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelperdisplayextensions.displayfor?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to know more. If you don't return model, it will display nothing, not null error.

Comment: @PrageethLiyanage MODEL.OutPutText  use model binding, it  need the model object, but @HTML.DisplayFor(m=>m.Output) don't need, DisplayFor<TModel,TResult>(IHtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel,TResult>>) : Returns HTML markup for the expression, using a display template. The template is found using the expression's ModelMetadata.